# Gradle experimental - add assembly file to sources

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, gradle-experimental

I am building a JNI application using Android studio and gradle experimental plugin 0.7.0

I want to add an assembly file (*.s) to the list of source files but I can't figure it out.

I have used `srcDirs` but it seems it only adds C/C++ files, I can't find `srcFiles` it says it does not exist and `include` directive is not working as well (and reported by many that it is not working)

So any one can help